# How to pick up a column of class factor which has values of 1 only in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a column in my dataset which stores family IDs. I made it a factor column, as it has over 615 entries and some of them are big families while some only have 1 entry. Each of these families are given a unique ID.  I now want to count how many of these are single entries (where the count for that factor is 1) and how many are 1 or more, signifying there is a family.

Is there a clever way of doing this? I have been trying to play around with factor, table, count commands and I am not sure how to do this. I would appreciate any help. I am working on R. [image]

Comment: Using table, the results that you are showing in the image, you are already half-way there. You just need to count how many are ==1.

Comment: Hello, so I've used table(count(dataframe$col == 1)) and get an error that says "Error in UseMethod ( "count" ) no applicable method for 'count'applied to an object of class "logical"
and get the same error the other way round too.

Comment: 1. there is no count function, use sum, 2. you need to reverse the order, first table then sum elements which ==1.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work. I tried this. count (table(tiering$Rare.Diseases.Family.Id)==1)
Error in UseMethod ( "count")
no applicable method for
'count' applied to an object of class
"cl'array
› table(sum(tiering$Rare.Diseases.Family.Id)==1)
Error in Summary.factor (c(218L,
218L. 231L. 231L.
231L.
234L.
234L
234L
' sum
not meaningful for factors

Comment: Again, 1. there is no count function, stop using it, 2. first do table and then on the results of table check which are ==1 and sum.

Comment: @Ar1229, user2974951 is trying to say, instead of `count(table(tiering$Rare.Diseases.Family.Id)==1)`, do `sum(table(tiering$Rare.Diseases.Family.Id)==1)` and you will get your answer. `count()` is not a `base` function. If you are using `dplyr::count()` or `plyr::count()`, you need to let us know. `dplyr::count()` and `plyr::count()` are used a bit differently, but they both work similar to the base `table()` – i.e., they give you the frequency counts, albeit in different formats.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step-by-step solution using `base` functions only:

```r
dataframe = data.frame(ID = paste0("s", c(1:5, 3:7))) # example dataset

table(dataframe$ID) # returns the count of each ID entry
#s1 s2 s3 s4 s5 s6 s7 
# 1  1  2  2  2  1  1 

table(dataframe$ID) == 1 # indicates TRUE for IDs that appear only once
#   s1    s2    s3    s4    s5    s6    s7 
# TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE 

sum(table(dataframe$ID) == 1) # sums the number of TRUEs
#[1] 4
```

**Extra:** If you also want the name of unique IDs that only have single entries, you can do:

```r
names(which(table(dataframe$ID) == 1))
#[1] "s1" "s2" "s6" "s7"
```

---

Here is an alternative approach if you are using the `dplyr` package:

```r
library(dplyr)

dataframe = data.frame(ID = paste0("s", c(1:5, 3:7))) # example dataset

filter(count(dataframe, ID), n == 1) # or, alternatively,

dataframe %>% count(ID) %>% filter(n == 1) # if you are familiar with piping
#  ID n
#1 s1 1
#2 s2 1
#3 s6 1
#4 s7 1

nrow(filter(count(dataframe, ID), n == 1)) # one of many ways to get the total count from the table
#[1] 4
```

Note that if you are also using the `plyr` package, R might mix up the `count()` from `dplyr` with `plyr` and give you an error for using the wrong one. In that situation, or just to avoid ambiguity, you can replace `count(ID)` with `dplyr::count(ID)` because that then specifies which `count()` function to use.